# LNK2019 Unresolved Symbol Even When The Linkage Exists

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, linkage

**PLATFORM**

Visual Studio 2010 Proffesional

**MY PROBLEM**

I have a solution called solution A. I have projects 'a' (static library containing internal and external header and source files) and 'b' (executable to see if 'a' functions can be used).

I intend to use static library 'a' functionality in another executable project 'c' which is in a **different** Solution C. What I have done is the following:

1) Added the static library folder (relative path) to the *Include Directories* section in my 'c' project properties (both debug and release configurations).

2) Checked the intellisense messenger to see whether or not the imports were successful.

Before I build solution C, everything was fine. However, as soon as I build it popped LNK2019 error because there is a function `foo()`that seemed to be unresolved. The (reported) function signatures are:

```
extern void foo(params);
extern void bar(void);
```

Just to remind the readers, `foo(params)` function is in static library 'a' in Solution A.

The error message I got was:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _foo
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _bar
```

**MY digagnosis so far**

The obvious diagnosis would be that:

1) the function signature reported seem to have a mismatch with my orignal one (I checked using real man's find and replace tool in visual studio; there is no mismatch).

2) Check for any include guards that is blocking it (I have checked once again, but it doesn't have any that will cause this problem).

The one things that I need to mention is that exec. project b in Solution 'C' can use `foo` and `bar` in static library a easily. That may be because they are in the same solution and by simply adding the project directory to *Include Directories* in the project b properties will do the job. But when I try to use it in a different solution, it is breaking down. I did a full clean and rebuild of the solution, but no luck.

I am starting to think that it cannot find the definition in the same header file and gets confused. Although the definition is in the identically-named source file, it may still get confused.

I am struggling to find a solution to this without having a full modification. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this problem by simply using "Add Reference" by right-clicking on the executable project where I was using it. However, I still had to manually import the static library project 'a' into the foreign solution C so that the referencing can be made.

I know it is not probably a good way of doing things, but it is definitely safer and I am pretty sure that it is going to work - one way or the other.